# Selenium XPath text search with single quote in substring

Tags: selenium, xpath

My html code will be like

```
<td class="summaryValRt2 summaryValDetails">Appledore Engineering v Shaw's - Dan Day_220217103442</td>
```

I use below `xpath` expression to click element operation.

```
//*[@class='summaryValRt2 summaryValDetails'][text()='Appledore Engineering v Shaw's - Dan Day_220217103442']
```

result:

> unable to click element due to non visibility of element

.

I checked it problem due to ' character in text
`[text()='Appledore Engineering v **Shaw's** - Dan Day_220217103442']`.

can any one share your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0, you can escape the quote with a backslash:

```
text()='Appledore Engineering v Shaw\'s - Dan Day_220217103442'
```

However, most major browsers do not support XPath 2.0 at this time. Until they do, you're limited to the XPath 1.0 spec, which does not support that escape character.

Since your string includes only single quotes, you could instead wrap the string in double quotes:

```
text()="Appledore Engineering v Shaw's - Dan Day_220217103442"
```

That will cover most cases, but it gets trickier if you're searching for a string that includes both single quotes *and* double quotes.

For example, suppose you are searching for the following string:

```
single'quote double"quote
```

You can achieve that using `concat` with the alternating quotes trick:

```
text()=concat("single'quote", ' double"quote')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `[text()='Appledore Engineering v Shaw\'s - Dan Day_220217103442']`, I used [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) in this example.

Or you could try with unicode code for single quote, something like `[text()='Appledore Engineering v Shaw\u0027s - Dan Day_220217103442']`

Comment: no its not working,as result same //*[@class='summaryValRt2 summaryValDetails'][text()='Appledore Engineering v Shaw\'s - Dan Day_220217103442']

Comment: That will work in XPath 2.0, but many browsers are still using XPath 1.0 at this time.

Comment: i am using latest version browser only.can u help me

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of the below xpath its working properly to me.

```
//*[@class='summaryValRt2 summaryValDetails'][text()="Appledore Engineering v Shaw's - Dan Day_220217103442"]
```

Comment: Hello @Ramesh your `xpath` is to lacate element in browser. but when i try to execute this `xpath` with java lang. it is not allowing me to write it, because of (double quotes) you were using inside your xpath. 

For more details on this, try to prepare above `xpath` script with `java` lang.

Comment: When will you update it? because your answer is not helpful for me.